# ARM: tst.w on register containing address

Tags: assembly, arm

Let's say you have this instruction:

```
tst.w r6, #0x1
```

and r6 contains the address of something, does it compare 0x1 to the address or the value at that address?

Comment: ARM is a load/store architecture and doesn't allow any direct operations on memory. The instruction will do a logical "AND" of R6 and 1 and change the flags accordingly.

Comment: It is like `bool test(void *p) { return (int)p & 1 ? true : false; }`, except it does the assembler version of `bool` and sets condition codes.  This is just like *dwelch's* answer, if you have drank the ARM cool-aid.

Answer (score 0):

read the manual

```
if ConditionPassed() then
EncodingSpecificOperations();
(shifted, carry) = Shift_C(R[m], shift_t, shift_n, APSR.C);
result = R[n] AND shifted;
APSR.N = result<31>;
APSR.Z = IsZeroBit(result);
APSR.C = carry;
// APSR.V unchanged
```

here

```
result = R[n] AND shifted;
```

and

```
(shift_t, shift_n) = DecodeImmShift(type, imm3:imm2);
```

So as BitBank said it ands the immediate with the register and adjusts the flags.

Comment: I'm downvoting because I don't see how this is in any way related to the question.